# How to save a docker container?

Tags: docker

Whenever I am using

> docker run -i -t ae8c587afa40  /bin/bash command

it always creates a new container with a new ID. Can someone help me on how to save that particular container so that whenever I exit from that container my data doesn't get lost?

Comment: Have you read the [official Docker tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)?  That’s a much better approach than trying to run interactive shells in containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the container in background by using the below option:

```
docker run -d --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 7180:7180 -p 8888:8888 -p 10000:10000 -p 8020:8020 -p 9092:9092 -p 9093:9093 -p 9393:9393 -p 9394:9394 -p 24042:24042  4239cd2958c6 /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

The -d option will help to run the container even if you exit from the terminal on which container was started. New container id will be created. The id present in the docker run command is the image id.

Comment: Which argument do I need to pass after  -d ? Because on my server all the containers have been deleted! So do I need to pass image ID?

Answer (score 0):

A docker container goes into the `stopped` state when you exit from the container.
You can view all docker containers (running and stopped) by using `docker ps -a`.
In this listing you will see your old container.

If you need to restart it you can do this:

`docker start -i <container_id>`

This will restart the stopped container.
See - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/ for further details on the `docker start` command.

**Note:** Having data inside a docker container is not a good idea. You should use volumes or bind mounts to save your data. A good idea is to treat containers as being ephemeral and immutable.

Edit:

To Detach from a container without exiting the shell/process running in the container use the Key sequence Control + P  Control + Q.
See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/

Comment: This command restarts the container but after exiting from the container, when I use docker ps command it does not list that container as the running container. What should I do to save that container because I want to use the docker cp command to copy data from server to that particular docker container?

Comment: see the answer, you need to use ```docker ps -a``` to see the stopped containers.

Comment: You can detach from a container and leave it running using the CTRL-p CTRL-q key sequence. See edit for links

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help me on how to save that particular container so that whenever I exit from that container my data doesn't get lost?

You **should not** rely on containers re usability. Instead of executing manually commands inside a container, build your own custom image including these commands. By doing this, you do not need to worry about starting a specific container cause all containers of that image will include the commands that you have defined when building the image.

Another advantage is that you can easily share your image via its Dockerfile or by pushing it to a repository.

I suggest that you read the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) to understand docker's concept.